# No overload for 'My Void' matches delegate 'My Delegate'?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, delegates

I have a user control with one custom event. This is in a Windows Phone app if it matters. The event in the user control's C# looks like this:

```
public delegate void TextChangedVoid(string newText)
public event TextChangedVoid TextChanged;
```

I then add this to my Window's XAML:

```
<local:ClientList TextChanged="clist_TextChanged"...
```

And in the Page's C#:

```
private void clist_TextChanged(string newText)
{
    ...
}
```

It looks fine, but every time I build my project I get this error:

```
No overload for 'clist_TextChanged' matches delegate 'TextChangedVoid'.
```

Why is this happening? Should I be using a class other than string in my event?

Comment: Actually the second time I build the solution it's not updated

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I should have been using a class besides string. I created a class inheriting from EventArgs to use to hold the string variable. This fixed the problem. It looked like:

```
public partial class ClientChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClientChangedEventArgs(string mewText)
    {
        this.NewText = newText;
    }
    public string NewText;
}
```

And in my User Control:

```
public delegate void TextChangedVoid(ClientChangedEventArgs e)
public event TextChangedVoid TextChanged;
```